# Formula for $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 \pm x^n)$

Tags: products, infinite-product, constants

I would like to find a formula for

$$f(x) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 + x^n)$$

$$g(x) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 - x^n)$$

In particular, $f(1/4)$ appears as the normalization factor for the CORDIC, the coefficients of $f(x)$ gives, coefficient gives the number of partitions of n into distinct parts; number of partitions of n into odd parts.[1](https://oeis.org/A000009).

I only know that that these functions can be expressed in terms of q-Pochhammer symbol.

Are there closed forms for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in terms of common functions. In particular, can $f(1/4)$ be expressed in a closed form?

Are there general any solutions for the finite products that could have some advantage compared to this definition?

Comment: We invented new notation for this kind for thing: the $q$-Pochhammer. [How to find the closed form of multiplications of exponentials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705469/how-to-find-the-closed-form-of-multiplications-of-exponentials)

Comment: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty$